# Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to delete a file from my visual studio project, but this dialogue pops up and prevent me from doing that. What does it mean and how do I resolve this problem?

There is a xamarin thread about this but no solution there.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25719/cannot-modify-an-evaluated-object-originating-in-an-imported-file

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have no idea what the real problem is, but we do find a fix by comparing this project with some other project files that we have.

The fix is to open the .Shared.vcxitems file in an text editor and replace this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)SourceItemsFromImports" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

with this

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="SourceItemsFromImports" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran across this question as well as a couple others related to the error message, specifically. My issue was different from the OP's as it had to do with NuGet packages not installing/uninstalling/updating.

I opened the `.CSProj` files only to see the package reference completely missing for `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, ie some VS file somewhere was caching this bad reference, even after killing all existing `.vs` directories. So I just added it manually, ran `nuget restore`, and was back in business.

Basically, I modified this block of project file XML:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.8</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

to this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>6.2.8</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk">
      <Version>16.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This modification to my .csproj was all it took to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for my unit testing as well. Confirmed this is still a problem with a new VS2019 UWP unit test [1/27/2021] project. Good grief. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Life saver. Can also confirm this worked [20/03/2021]!

Comment: Thanks. This is still an issue in VS 2022 Community Unit test project and this solution still works.

Answer (score 5):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution happend because there was NuGet packages source pointing to non-existent local folder, changed it in Package Manager Settings.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to open the `.vcxitems` and `.vcxitems.filters`, mentioned in the error message, in text editor and delete the file directly in the xml. Also I want to note that this error appears for me only when I tried to delete files that were part of different `.vcxitems` that was imported into main project. You can check your main project for `<Import Project="xyz.vcxitems" />`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was resolved by setting 'Default Package Management Format' to 'PackageReference' from 'PackageConfig' in Nuget Package Manager Settings

[image]